# ¿Como actualizar una contraseña encriptada con crypto?

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, mongoose

Estoy haciendo una app usando node y tengo un schema de usuarios tal que asi:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema();
const crypto = require('node:crypto');
const { v1 } = require('uuid');

const userSchema = new Schema({
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    username: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        required: true
    },
    hashed_password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    salt: String,
    status: {
        type: String,
        enum: ['pending', 'active'],
        default: 'pending'
    },
    confirmationCode: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
    },
    role: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0 //0 regular user, 1 admin
    }
}, {timestamps: true});


userSchema.virtual('password')
.set(function(password) {
    this._password = password;
    this.salt = v1();
    this.hashed_password = this.encryptPassword(password);
})
.get(function(){
    return this._password;
})

userSchema.methods = {
    authenticate: function(plainText) {
        return this.encryptPassword(plainText) === this.hashed_password;
    },

    encryptPassword: function(password) {
        if(!password) return '';
        try {
            return crypto.createHmac('sha1', this.salt)
            .update(password)
            .digest('hex');
        } catch(err) {
            return '';
        }
    }
}


module.exports = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
```

Estoy haciendo el controlador e hice una funcion para poder hacer el update de los datos usando la funcion findByIdAndUpdate de mongoose.
Sin embargo, al ejecutar el codigo y llamar a la funcion, el usuario se actualiza todo excepto la contraseña. Ya intente de varias formas pero no funciono. ¿Alguno sabe como hacerlo correctamente? Soy nuevo haciendo autenticacion usando crypto y estuve buscando en la documentación por internet pero no encontre nada que me ayude.

Comment: Pero... segun entiendo las propiedades `virtual` de `mongoose` están hechas justo para no guardarse en la base de datos. Porque esperarías que se guardara el password? Si estás esperando que se guarden las propiedades `_password`, `salt` y `hashed_password` primero debes leer sobre `strict mode` que por defecto es true... e indica a mongoose que no almacene en la base de datos propiedades que no están en el schema. Entonces, o agregas esas propiedades al schema o usas `$set` con `strict=false` para cambiar el comportamiento https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/document.html#document_Document-set